# Using AngularJS <div ng-app=""> in Facelets causes warning "Undefined attribute name (ng-app)"

Tags: angularjs, jsf, xhtml, facelets

I am building web site using JSF, so that I use Facelets as view technology. Facelets is XHTML+XML based. 
Now I want to use AngularJS into my project. I read tutorial here: 
http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_intro.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div ng-app="">

<p>Input something in the input box:</p>
<p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name" value="John"></p>
<p ng-bind="name"></p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I push above code in to a file `test.xhtml`. But a warning appears:

> Undefined attribute name (ng-app)

How can I modify XHTML so that it understands AngularJS?

Comment: Any reason you're using xhtml? If so you'll probably have to prefix angular attributes with `data-` for example `ng-app` would have to be `data-ng-app` and use the correct xhtml document declaration. I would just go with html.

Comment: I am using xhtml because my project based on JSF to interactive with bean. Can you tell me more detail? I dont know why I cannot post the code with html here, it;'s hidden

Comment: Sadly that's my extent of knowledge on xhtml. To format code on stackoverflow you have to indent four spaces.

Comment: sounds more like an IDE issue than anything else. Set your IDE config to ignore it or use `data-` before all directive attributes. And store it as `.html` file

Comment: Where are you using XHTML at all here? Is it the generated HTML code?

Comment: No, My xhtml file is all for view layer. For example an file xhtml like this
[code]
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
 xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions"
 xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
      <f:view contentType="text/html">
           <h:head >
         <title>imetro</title>
     </h:head>
            <h:body>
              //
            </h:body>
      </f:view>
   </html>
[/code]

Answer (score 0):

This warning is coming from the editor, not from JSF. The editor is during validation just thinking that you're brand new to this all and possibly made a mistake, because this attribtue is not recognizable as standard JSF/Facelets. You can safely ignore the warning and run the code straight away. It should run and work fine.

You can reconfigure the editor to not show the warning anymore. You did unfortunately not tell anywhere which editor you're using, so it's merely guessing based on the exact error message. The exact error message is recognizable as the one coming from Eclipse. I can reproduce it here:

[image]

Do you notice that Eclipse was so friendly to show quick fixes as well? Pick the one which says "Ignore 'ng-app' attribute in valiation" (or perhaps the one saying 'ng-*' attributes). It'll bring you to Eclipse  validation preferences with the excluded attribtues prefilled:

[image]

Just click OK and then do a rebuild/revalidate. Now the warning should disappear:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to let JSF insert a pass-through attribute. If you swap `<div ng-app="">` with JSF' `<h:panelGroup layout="block">` you can give JSF control over that div's attributes:

```
<html 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
/>
...
<h:panelGroup layout="block">
    <f:passThroughAttribute name="ng-app" value=""/>
</h:panelGroup>
...
</html>
```

See [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets009.htm), section **8.9.2 Using Pass-Through Attributes**.